# how i get col index on mouse down of class in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        15
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        30
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        45
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function(e) {
    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
}
```

How can I get the column index on mouse down of class in jQuery?

Comment: it's not clear whether you want column or row index

Comment: You could try jquery index(); http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the column, you may use the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function :

```
$(".csstablelisttd td").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var colIndex = $(this).index();
});
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/z9x5g/1/)

Note that you must have the event detected on the `td`, not the `tr`.

Comment: This doesn't change the HTML.

Comment: i have to get coloumn index on mouse down of only css class no extra td

Comment: How to add class on current colIndex

Answer (score 1):

The column index would be the following:

```
$('.csstablelisttd').mousedown(function (e) {
    var colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
});
```

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jquYB/1/).

Comment: Thaks I have one problem I have to add class only above colIndex on mousedown

Comment: $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstdhighlight");

Comment: How to add class on current colIndex

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. You can use children('eq(' + colIndex + ')') also gt(colIndex), etc.

Comment: select only one coloumn at a time expects

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is checking the `index` of the `tr`, select the `td` instead:

```
$(".csstablelisttd td").live('mousedown', function(e) {
    idx = $(this).index();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CJm9y/)

Answer (score 0):

You're listening for an event on the row itself, which by definition spans all available columns within the table. You can do something like this:

```
$('tr.csstablelisttd td').on('mouseover', function()
{
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)),
        row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

    alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
});
```

Comment: How to add class on current colIndex